# Casting [Any?] to [Any] without a warning

Tags: swift

I am using `FMDatabase`, and want to pass it an array of parameters that may contain optional values.  This compiles fine, but the problem is that I can't get it to work without getting a warning about implicit coercion.  If I pass it an `[Any?]` array I get a warning in the function, but if I pass it an `[Any]` array I get a warning whenever I add an optional to the array.  The best I've been able to do is cut it down to a single warning with this code:

```
extension FMDatabase {
    func executeQuery(_ sql: String, withArgumentsIn: [Any?]) -> FMResultSet {
        // generates a warning:
        // "Expression implicitly coerced from 'Any?' to Any"
        return self.executeQuery(sql, withArgumentsIn: withArgumentsIn as [Any])
    }
}
```

I know you can use `as Any` to avoid that problem with a regular `Any` object, but I can't figure out how to do it with an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `map` to convert `[Any?]` to `[Any]`.

```
let a: [Any?] = [1, true, Optional("hello"), nil]
let b = a.map { $0 as Any }

print(type(of: a))  // Array<Optional<Any>>
print(a)            // [Optional(1), Optional(true), Optional("hello"), nil]

print(type(of: b))  // Array<Any>
print(b)            // [Optional(1), Optional(true), Optional("hello"), nil]
```